# For loop not working. Syntax error

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have this javascript that dosn't work. The h2020 element change into display: none only if the "cb9" checkbox is checked. Anyone can help me?
Thanks a lot!
This is the page link: http://iris-sissa.sissa.it/main/h2020itv3.html

```
<script language="javascript">
  function HideH2020() {
    var i = 1; 
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      if (document.getElementById('cb' + i).checked) {
        document.getElementById("h2020").style.display = "none";
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("h2020").style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is not Java.

Comment: What is the Sintax error?  Do you need to change it to `for (var i...`?

Comment: @sykoy , its syntax error not sintax
what is the error on console when you run this script?

Comment: *If I set var i = 1; the script works fine.* and *I do not find the way to do the "for" loop working.* are kind of contradicting each other.

Comment: This script loops over 9 checkboxes but only if the last checkbox is checked it will hide the `h2020` element

Comment: Are you shure there are 9 checkboxes with ids from cb1 to cb9? And have you thought about a class maybe?

Comment: @endless that wasnt addressed to you but to the OP

Comment: there is no such element as `document.getElementById('cb0')` you will get null instead

Comment: @endless YOU ARE RIGHT! good suggestion!

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. You also don't need to append _resolved_ to the title. Instead you can accept an answer which will tell others that the question is now solved. You can find your code in your [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45053095/revisions). This is to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Could be a theme of scope of definition of var i.
When you're using without "var", is a global definition ofi , so would be prevoius definition as i=11, or ended loop thn i will at second time as 10, then the for fdoes run.

But works when in the for (var i=1, this is why worrks, becose in every definition of for works. And the scope is own of the for, and no one can change it in any part of your full code.

Comment: @Jonasw but i tell you,. that you are usin a i as a global var, and i dont see if you got in all code any previous definition of (for i=0; i<12, . You must get the concept of this not the code